# Modifying FlaskForms class - object has no attribute '_fields'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a FlaskForm that changes depending on the customer passed to it and having issues when the HTML is getting rendered.  I haven't done much work with classes unfortunately so I'm not sure what the issue is.  I get an error in Python that says:

```
AttributeError: 'GlobalsForm' object has no attribute '_fields'
```

I modified the __init__ so that you can set who the customer is plus a created a class function that checks to see who the customer is and customizes the form fields depending on who the customer is.  I have a feeling it doesn't like me modifying the class I am inheriting and am probably missing something to make it work.  Need to do something with "super"?

Here is what I have so far:

**routes.py**

```
@app.route('/global_vars', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def global_vars():

    data = session.get('dev_data', None)
    form = GlobalsForm(customer=data['customer'])
    form.set_fields()
    return render_template('global_vars.html', title='Config Provisioning - Globals', form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class GlobalsForm(FlaskForm):

    def __init__(self, customer):
            self.customer = customer

    def set_fields(self):
        if self.customer == 'Cust1':
            site_choices = [('Site1', 'Site1'), ('Site2', 'Site2'), ('Site3', 'Site3')]
            site = SelectField('Site: ', choices = site_choices)
            floor_room = StringField("Floor/Room (Ex. FL1RM56 or 1J46): ", validators=[InputRequired()])
            rack = StringField("Rack (Data Centers only): ")
            l2_domain_choices = [('USR', 'USR - User'), ('DC', 'DC - Data Center'), ('OOBM', 'OOBM - Out of Band Management')]
            l2_domain = SelectField('Layer 2 Domain: ', choices=l2_domain_choices)
            function_choices = [('ACSW', 'ACSW - Access Switch)'), ('AGSW', 'AGSW - Aggregation Switch'), ('CRSW', 'CRSW - Core Switch')]
            function = SelectField('Device function: ', choices=function_choices)
        else:
            hostname = Stringfield("Hostname: ", validators=[InputRequired()])
```

Comment: I added **super().__init__(self)** to the __init__ which fixed my initial problem, now I'm getting **object has no attribute 'getlist'** so im probably still missing something having to do with the parent class...

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out..  Had to expand on the super() line...

```
class GlobalsForm(FlaskForm):

    def __init__(self, customer=None, *args, **kwargs):
            self.customer = customer
            super(GlobalsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```